# Reading a txt file using scanner class get InputMismatchException. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and following examples from Murach's Java book. I am currently learning how to work with records. I have run into an issue which I cannot seem to resolve. The logic compiles without any issues, however when I try to run the program, I get "INputMismatchException" error on line 23 in "ReadRecords" class. I have googled this issue and searched SOF about this very issue, I did find couple of the solutions, but they didn't help. I would highly appreciate it if someone can help me sort this issue out, please. I have a these classes:

1. Records Class
2. ReadRecords Class

Code for Records Class:

```
class Records{

    public int id;              //ID
    public String name;         //NAME
    public String gender;       //GENDER

}//CLASS
```

Code for ReadRecords Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadRecords {

    //METHOD: MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Scanner input;                              
        final int MAX_LEN = 25;                     
        int counter = 0;                                
        String filePath = "files/records.txt";      

        Records[] rec = new Records[ MAX_LEN ];     
        File file;      

        try {
            file = new File( filePath );
            input = new Scanner( file );

            do{             
                rec[counter].id = input.nextInt();      //INT
                rec[counter].name = input.next();   //STRING
                rec[counter].gender = input.next(); //STRING
                ++counter;
            }
            while(rec[counter -1].id != 0);
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ){       
            System.out.println( "File access error" );  
            counter = 0;
        }//

        System.out.println(rec[0].name);
    }// 
}//
```

Text file "records.txt"

```
1, Adam, male
2, Bella, female
3, Charlie, male
4, David, male
5, Elizabeth, female
6, Frank, male
7, Ginger, female
8, Harry, male
9, Irene, female
10, Jill, female
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Did you try my answer??

Answer (score 2):

The input you are searching is `int`, but you have `string` in first place so you are getting inputMismatchException as the default delimter of scanner is space,

In your text file you have ", " as delimiter.so use that

```
input = new Scanner( file ).useDelimiter(", ");
```

And secondly `rec[counter].id` throws `NullPointerException` as you initially will have null values in the array. so change that as shown below

```
do{        
                Records record=new Records();
                record.id = input.nextInt();      //INT
                record.name = input.next();   //STRING
                record.gender = input.next(); //STRING
                rec[counter]=record;
                ++counter;
            }
            while(input.nextLine() != null);
```

Comment: Thank you, @gowtham for your suggestion and code. I did try it out, it compiles well, but I get the "InputMismatchException" error at line 23 which is this line:  record.id = input.nextInt();      //INT

Comment: It is working for me. Just try assigning it to an int variable and assign the variable to record.id

Comment: I took your suggestion and created three variables: Int Id = input.nextInt(), String Name = input.next(), String Gender = input.next(). Then I assigned record.id = Id, record.name = Name, record.gender = Gender. All compiles well, but still the same runtime error.thx

Answer (score 1):

Default delimter of scanner is space, but in your text file you have data seperated by space as well as new line charater. So you need to use delimiter as ', ' as well as '\n\r'.

Also you can change your wile condition to

while (input.hasNext() && (input.next() != null));

Here is the modified code of your's which ran for me. To simply the things, I removed all the commas in your txt file and used the following pattern as delimter - [ \r\n]. And it ran succesfully.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Records
{

    public int id; // ID
    public String name; // NAME
    public String gender; // GENDER

}// CLASS

public class ReadRecords
{

    // METHOD: MAIN
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = null;
        final int MAX_LEN = 25;
        int counter = 0;
        final String filePath = "records.txt";

        final Records[] rec = new Records[MAX_LEN];
        File file;

        try
        {
            file = new File(filePath);
            input = new Scanner(file);
            final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[ \r\n]");
            input.useDelimiter(pat);
            do
            {
                rec[counter] = new Records();
                rec[counter].id = input.nextInt(); // INT
                rec[counter].name = input.next(); // STRING
                rec[counter].gender = input.next(); // STRING
                ++counter;

            }
            while (input.hasNext() && (input.next() != null));
        }
        catch (final IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("File access error");
            counter = 0;
        }//

        System.out.println(rec[0].name);
    }//
}//
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish for all you help. I copied and pasted your code without making any edits and compiled it without any issues. However I am still getting "InputMismatchException" error on line 28.

Comment: Did you edited your text file too. Remove all the commas from your file and the code will work

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly use a different method of accessing the text file.  Google FileReader as well as BufferedReader, they are the file accessors I was told to use in my intro classes. I will post below the code I came up with to get the Records objects created from the text file.  It is by no means the best way to do it, but it does get the job done.  Feel free to ask questions about the code I used that may be unfamiliar.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Records {

    public int id;              //ID
    public String name;         //NAME
    public String gender;       //GENDER

}


public class ReadRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "records.txt";      

        ArrayList<Records> rec = new ArrayList<Records>();           

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String nextLine;
            String splitText[];

            while((nextLine = br.readLine())!= null){
                Records temp = new Records();
                splitText = nextLine.split(", ");
                temp.id = Integer.parseInt(splitText[0]);
                temp.name = splitText[1];
                temp.gender = splitText[2];
                rec.add(temp);

            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ){       
            System.out.println( "File access error" );  
        }//

        for (int i = 0; i < rec.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Record ID: " + rec.get(i).id 
                    + "\n" + "Record Name: " + rec.get(i).name + "\n" + "Record Gender: " + rec.get(i).gender);
        }
    }// 

}
```

On a side note, I would suggest downloading an IDE such as Eclipse for ease of use.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and code. I am learning how to manipulate the arrays and haven't gotten to ArrayList yet. If it is not too much too ask, can your code be done using an Array as I have in my code, please. Thx